# How is this nil key into the hash?

Tags: json, ruby, parsing

I was trying to implement a json parser. The input was

```
"{ \"key\": { \"foo\": \"bar\", \"hello\" : 100 } }"
```

which I formatted into

```
"{key:{foo:bar,hello:100}}"
```

which I then tokenize to get an array like this

```
["{", "key", ":", "{", "foo", ":", "bar", ",", "hello", ":", "100", "}", "}"]
```

I may have ignored the `,` too. Anyway, when I tried to build ruby hash from that array, I get this

```
{nil=>{"key"=>{"foo"=>"bar", "hello"=>"100"}}}
```

I don't know how this `nil` is being used as key. This is the method I'm using to build the hash

```
def build_hash(arr)
  h = {}
  keys = []
  while arr.size > 0
    current_token = arr.shift
    if alpha?(current_token)
      if keys.empty? # that means a new key is to be expected
        keys << current_token
      else
        h[keys.pop] = current_token
      end
    elsif current_token == '}'
      # these shouldn't be any key left in the keys stack. if there is one, raise error
      # otherwise close the hash and return from method
      if not keys.empty?
        raise_invalid_format_error
      else
        return h
      end
    elsif current_token == ','
      # continue reading. new key will appear. There shouldn't be any key in keys[]
      raise_invalid_format_error unless keys.empty?
    elsif current_token == '{'
      # this means new hash is starting, nested. Should be a value to a key
      # recursive call, assign the result to the existing key
      h[keys.pop] = build_hash(arr)
    end
  end
  h
end
```

Method `alpha?` returns true if the character is a letter or digit

```
def alpha?(s)
  s.match(/\A[[:alnum:]]+\z/)
end
```

What's going on here?

Comment: why not simply:
`require('json'); JSON.parse("{ \"key\": { \"foo\": \"bar\", \"hello\" : 100 } }");`

Comment: @JanZeiseweis Yeah, I knew that. But not using any library was a requirement

Comment: Apart from that, you first element is a '{' (I'm not sure what alpha? is doing) but if `alpha?` returns false, you jump to the last `elsif current_token == '{'` and since keys is empty, `keys.pop` returns `nil`.

Comment: @JanZeiseweis oh. I forgot the `alpha?`, it returns true if it is a letter or a number

Comment: In the last `elsif` you should only do `h[keys.pop] = build_hash(arr)` only if you keys is not empty ;)

Comment: @JanZeiseweis yes. Adding condition fixes it. You may add an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i described in the comments, only pop a key if there is one:

```
def build_hash(arr)
  h = {}
  keys = []
  while arr.size > 0
    current_token = arr.shift
    if alpha?(current_token)
      if keys.empty? # that means a new key is to be expected
        keys << current_token
      else
        h[keys.pop] = current_token
      end
    elsif current_token == '}'
      # these shouldn't be any key left in the keys stack. if there is one, raise error
      # otherwise close the hash and return from method
      if not keys.empty?
        raise_invalid_format_error
      else
        return h
      end
    elsif current_token == ','
      # continue reading. new key will appear. There shouldn't be any key in keys[]
      raise_invalid_format_error unless keys.empty?
    elsif current_token == '{'
      # this means new hash is starting, nested. Should be a value to a key
      # recursive call, assign the result to the existing key
      if keys.any?
        h[keys.pop] = build_hash(arr)
      end
    end
  end
  h
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The very first token in your array will be `{`, which will fall through to your final `elsif` case:

```
elsif current_token == '{'
  # this means new hash is starting, nested. Should be a value to a key
  # recursive call, assign the result to the existing key
  h[keys.pop] = ....
```

The `keys` array is empty, so `pop` returns `nil`, which you use as a key for your hash.

Comment: Got it now. thanks. upvoted :) I accepted Jan's answer, since he first answered it in comment.